# Use a selected item from a dropdownlist in a SELECT query

Tags: sql, asp.net, select, drop-down-menu

I have following code which is a drop down list of flight locations:

```
Where to:<br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        DataTextField="Destination" 
        DataValueField="Destination" Width="222px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Destination] FROM [tblFlight]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want to be able to use the selected value from the drop down list above (one of them is Corfu) as the WHERE condition of a query that will only select the flights going to Corfu.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

basically:

`string dest = yourDropDown.SelectedItem;
 SELECT [Destination] FROM [tblFlight] WHERE [Destination] = " + dest;`

Comment: I realised that I had the WHERE condition in the wrong place. Where the information is to displayed I have the following code: 

`<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT tblAirport.Name, tblFlight.Destination, tblFlight.FlightDate FROM tblAirport INNER JOIN tblFlight ON tblAirport.AirportCode = tblFlight.AirportCode WHERE Destination = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value"></asp:SqlDataSource>` 

But from this I get errors saying "DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value" could not be bound. Ideas?

Comment: try specifying the table in the WHERE clause: `WHERE tblFlight.Destination = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value`. not sure if that's enough though.